# ArcGIS database feature class editor default version settings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.5, versioning

I created an enterprise geodatabase with ArcCatalog 10.5 in my PostgreSQL database. And I created feature class in database. But when I add feature class in arcmap, I need to change the editor settings.

[image]

I uncheck the checkbox of "Edit a version of the database with the ability to undo and redo" every time. Can I set this only one time as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no registry setting for this so launching ArcMap will always prompt to uncheck the option for non-versioned editing.  There are a couple of ways around this though.

1. Register the feature class as versioned.
2. Open a new map document, set the editing option to edit non-versioned data.  Save the map document.  Use this blank map document to launch ArcMap.  The "without the ability to undo/redo" setting will be saved.
3. Launch ArcMap, make the setting change.  Open new map documents using File > New.  The option will remain unchecked while in this ArcMap session.

This might be a good candidate for ArcGIS Ideas.
https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/

UPDATE:  It looks like this has been an "idea" for some time now.
https://community.esri.com/ideas/2508